# Выполнение операций перед закрытием приложения android

Tags: java, android-studio, android-asynctask

Цель: Мне нужно запустить несколько методов перед тем как моё приложение полностью закроется после того как я выгрузил его из памяти. 
Метод onDestroy() вызывается только тогда когда я выхожу из приложение в нём самом, т.е нажал кнопку назад или вызвал метод finish(). Но каждый раз когда я скрываю приложение вызывается метод onPause() и если в то время пока оно на паузе я его закрою то метод onDestroy() не вызывается. 
А выполнить методы мне нужно только перед тем как приложение полностью закроется а не во время паузы потому что у меня поддерживается соединение с сервером. И на фоне мне это соединение нужно но не тогда когда я его закрываю 
Надеюсь проблема вам будет понятна

Таки куда мне запихать те методы чтобы они вызывались только перед закрытием ?
Буду очень благодарен

Comment: В android нет адекватного способа отследить событие закрытия приложения.

Comment: Нашел недочет в серверной части и теперь мне не нужно отслеживать закрытие.
Но было бы не плохо знать даже какой нибудь даже неадекватный способ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как уже сказали ранее. Адекватного способа нет.